# Visual Studio mark everything with green squiggly lines

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

I was coding a windows 10 uwp app. All of a sudden all my files starting getting green squiggly lines under them. I've tried cleaning, rebuilding, exiting visual studio, restarting computer, and even creating a new blank windows 10 uwp app using Template 10. None of this has solved my problems. I can't remember exactly what I did to cause this problem in the first place. I remember selecting one of the "Show potential fix". In the first image all the using are marked in green. And in the second image the project compiles fine but it is giving red marks all over.

How do I get rid of the green squiggly lines?

[image]
[image]

Update: added another image with red lines.

Comment: Looks like StyleCop to me

Comment: I didn't install StyleCop plugin. I thought it was weird because "Using * " is all marked. That shouldn't be happening.

Comment: What does it say if you mouseover erroneous lines? What choices are there if you click on the lightbulb button.

Comment: It is saying something like "Using directive must appear within a namespace declaration" And the "Show potential fixes" have "Reoder using statements" and "Remove unnecessary using"

Comment: You did not have to install StyleCop. Look to the Analyzers section in References in your project, maybe it was installed with some dependency as an analyzer

Comment: Right so "StyleCop.Analyzers" and "StyleCop.Analyzers.CodeFixes" is listed under there. I don't remember turning them on or off. How do I remove them?